# Objectively speaking, can chanting be beneficial in any way?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, utilitarianism

Chanting rituals are part of almost all religions, and also many non-religious groupings e.g. martial arts schools, political activist groups, etc. The content of chanting varies from the simplistic and individualistic (e.g. the monosyllabic OM in Hinduism), to the highly complex and coordinated (e.g. Anglican psalm chanting).

Why do people across the globe seem driven to chant? Are there any objective (i.e. non-denominational) explanations for such beliefs and such behaviours in philosophy? And are there any obvious benefits to chanting that one may identify from a philosophical standpoint?

Comment: It's an interesting question; but this seems like a question that might be asked in comparative cultural anthropology rather than philosophy; it's also tremendously broad - you're jumping from the secular to the sacred, from one country to another; from one cultural context to another; simply discovering or theorising rationales doesn't make it philosophy.

Comment: What do you mean by "objectively"?  For instance, is it "objective" if chanting puts someone in a deep, pleasurable trance state?  By objective, do you mean a chant's ability to affect the outside world or do you mean any measurable change, even in subjectivity?

Comment: And "chanting" before a rugby match can demoralize your opponent and make it easier to win. Most definitely an objective advantage.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Philosophy is the study of the general and fundamental nature of reality, existence, knowledge, values, reason, mind, and language. In casual speech, the term can refer to any of "the most basic beliefs, concepts, and attitudes of an individual or group," So, why is this question outside the domain of philosophy?

Comment: @R.Barzell - Objectively meaning without bringing any religious beliefs into this discussion, or relying heavily on scriptural authority.

Comment: It's because 'it's casual speech' that it's akin to anthropology which gives thick descriptions of actually lived experience; it's structural anthropolgy that looks for the kind of patterns that you are looking for: for example Levi-Strauss did this for kinship relationships, I think in the Amazon; and quite amazingly came up with a definite mathematical formulae for this.

Comment: This question might be better suited to (a) social anthropology, (b) physical anthropology, (c) cultural studies, (d) neuroscience... depending on the type of explanation you seek. but it's not a question normally dealt with in philosophy.

Comment: @KrishnarajRao you could look at it psychologically. There may have been some studies on how certain repetitive, regular activities can put one in trance-like/meditative states.  From there, you could argue that those states -- inasfar as they are pleasurable -- are objectively beneficial to the persons involved.

Comment: @R.Barzell and there can certainly be many benefits beyond just pleasure. Creative activities and sports develop Executive Functioning. As such they improve whole-brain integration and deepen present-moment awareness. I would say that this is the reason for the widespread use of chanting in a spiritual context: because it is effective in furthering spiritual development. People usually persist in doing things over the long term because they work, not just because they feel good. Else we would be a species of grasshoppers, not ants. That is to say: deceased. (Aesop's fable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Schopenhauer](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schopenhauer-aesthetics/#SubSidAesExp) was a philosophical pessimist; he judged that all life manifested Will; and expresses itself in perpetual striving; and that this was:

> a kind of *servitude* to the Will and to its attendant egoism

Hence the pessimism; however he held that there were three main ways in which the individual intellect - the man or woman - broke free of this; one of which is:

> Through aesthetic experience and artistic production

and he holds that nearly everyone is capable of this to some degree, otherwise they would be:

> absolutely insensitive to beauty and sublimity

Chanting, in sacred liturgy is done in a specific form that has its own aesthetic character: Gregorian chant, Islamic sufic Qawaali, or Anglican Hymns; they are notably done as a group, and because of the complex character of the liturgy, an individual resigns his 'embodied existence' by coming together as a group; and participating as a group in the same experience.

One could add too, that for Schopenhauer music itself expressed most closely the character of the Will, because it is in its essence, most closely associated with the expression of time - of time passing: a succession of notes; so by making oneself into a 'musical instrument' one is most closest to this Will.

Comment: Sounds like the pathway to Nonduality to me! Thus, the connection to religious and spiritual practice. I have used the phrase "*The shape of Time*" to express the relation between what is and unfolding / development, especially of people. We are the shape of time. Music is an analogy. **Where does the music go when the performance ends?**